# jscrollpane jquery button to change height and width

Tags: jquery, width, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a horizontal jscrollpane containing images.

the images have a default height of 400px and i want to make a button "small" that would change the height of the images to 200px (for example). of course the width also changes to keep proportions.

first i have this code to calculate the total width of images:

```
$(window).load(function(){

$('.scroll-content').each(function(){
var wrapper = $(this);
var wrapperWidth = 0;


    wrapper.find('.scroll-content-item img').each(function(){
        wrapperWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true) + 20;
    });

    wrapper.css('width', wrapperWidth);
```

and does the job great. then i initialize the jscrollpane:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```

and then the button:

```
$('.minus-button').click(function() {
$(".scroll-content-item img, .scroll-content-item, .jspContainer").css('height', 300); 
});
```

how can i add a function or call it again, to re-calculate the total width of images and give it to `.scroll-content`, but once the click is done.

any ideas?

thanks all for the time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the code in the window.load function create a separate function and call that function again.

Example

```
function calculateWidth() {}
    $('.scroll-content').each(function(){
      var wrapper = $(this);
      var wrapperWidth = 0;

      wrapper.find('.scroll-content-item img').each(function(){
        wrapperWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true) + 20;
      });

      wrapper.css('width', wrapperWidth);
    }
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
}

$(window).load(function() { calculateWidth(); })

$('.minus-button').click(function() {
    $(".scroll-content-item img, .scroll-content-item, .jspContainer").css('height', 300);
    calculateWidth(); 
});
```

You'll notice that I call the jScrollPane() function in the calculateHeight function. That is to reinitialize the jscrollpanes after it was resized. Note that you could also use the jscrollPane API method called [reinitialise](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) but you need to be more familiar with it. From experience, it's better to go through the API but calling the function again will give the same result.

Comment: hi @ComputerArts ! thanks for taking the time to explain and show how to make this work, however seems i am doing something wrong, the jscrollpane is not working at all. you can see my try here: http://bit.ly/TJaqC6

Comment: Well you're not setting the correct wrapperWidth to the container once it's smaller. Here: '$(".scroll-content, .jspContainer").css('width', wrapperWidth);' you're setting the same wrapperWidth calculated on the window load function.

Comment: this is my code right now: http://snipt.org/xgiid3
i need the initial load. so i can tell the jscrollpane what's the width. if i add yours after i am getting some errors. 
thanks a lot for taking the time on this